# Razor: adding dynamic values together

Tags: razor

I have a set of values that are generated dynamically with a foreach loop, how can I add these into one value?

For instance, say I have a site where each node has a number associated with it. How can I add all *these* numbers together? So far I've figured it'd be something similar to the following, where the value of 'node.aNumberValue' is added to the next one, and so on:

```
@foreach (var x in nodes){

    var total = node.aNumberValue + node.aNumberValue (etc...);

    <p>@total</p>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want, I think:

```
int total = 0;
@foreach (var x in nodes)
{
    total += x.aNumberValue;
}
<p>@total</p>
```

Or even better, just:

```
<p>@nodes.Sum(x => x.aNumberValue)</p>
```

Comment: Wow that's awesome, I've been working all day on this! Thanks!